# Select dynamically a list of char in a string form a DLL

Tags: c#, string, select

I'm new here and my English will not be the best you'll read today.
I just imported from a DLL a list of "key"

> (#8yg54w-#95jz#e-##9ixop-#7ps-#ny#9qv-#+pzbk5-#bp669x-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#fbhstu-#ehddtk-####9py),

we will name it this way it's a simple string.
I need to select the "key" that compose this string after each # but it has to be done dynamically and not like you choose in an ArrayList [0,1,2 ...].
The end result should look like 8yg54w and after u got this one it's a loop and u get the next one, which means 95jz#e. The first "#" is a separator for each key.
I wanna know how can I proceed to get each key after the first separator.
I'll try to answer your questions because I think that there will be some, this is probably poorly explained, I apologize in advance! Thanks

Comment: What will be the output of `####9py`?

Comment: You mentioned "ArrayList". I hope you're not using ArrayLists. Please forget that ArrayLists exist and use either List<> or Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This should return an array of keys.

`string.Split("-#");`

When you just need the string:

```
string x = "(#8yg54w-#95jz#e-##9ixop-#7ps-#ny#9qv-#+pzbk5-#bp669x-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#fbhstu-#ehddtk-####9py)";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("-", x.Split("-#")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

```cs
string input = "(#8yg54w-#95jz#e-##9ixop-#7ps-#ny#9qv-#+pzbk5-#bp669x-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#fbhstu-#ehddtk-####9py)";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=\#)[A-Za-z1-9#]+(?=-)");
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
8yg54w
95jz#e
#9ixop
7ps
ny#9qv
bp669x
bp6696
bp6696
bp6696
bp6696
bp6696
fbhstu
ehddtk
```

Explanation of the regular expression `(?<=\#)[A-Za-z1-9#]+(?=-)`

- General form `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` finds the pattern `find` between a `prefix` and a `suffix`.
- `(?<=\#)` prefix `#` (escaped with `\`).
- `[A-Za-z1-9#]` character set to match (upper and lower case letters + digits + #).
- `+` quantifier: At leat one character.
- `(?=-)` suffix `-`.

I am not sure whether the `)` is part of string. To get the last key `###9py` if the string contains `)` use `(?<=\#)[A-Za-z1-9#]+(?=-|\))` where `\)` is the right brace escaped. If `)` is in there, use `(?<=\#)[A-Za-z1-9#]+(?=-|$)` where `$` is the end of the string. `|` means OR. I.e., the suffix is either '-' OR `)` or it is `-` OR `$` (end of line).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may be a simple function that returns an `IEnumerable<string>`. You can accomplish this by splitting the string and using the `yield` keyword to return an iterator. E.g.

```cs
// Define the splitting function
public IEnumerable<string> GetKeys(string source) {
  var splitted = source.Split("-#");
  foreach (var key in splitted)
    yield return key;
}

// Use it in your code
var myKeys = GetKeys("#8yg54w-#95jz#e-##9ixop-#7ps-#ny#9qv-#+pzbk5-#bp669x-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#bp6696-#fbhstu-#ehddtk-####9py");

foreach(var k in myKeys) {
  // This will print your keys in the console one per line.
  Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

You can use this approach but I suggest to better hide the logic to get the nex Key if you need it to be a Unique Gobal Key generator. Using a static class with only a `GetNextKey()` method that can be the combination of the code above...